# Rails Asset Pipeline is not loading my javascript file (why won't this code work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This code works if I include it in the view itself and it works if I include it directly into the Application.js file, but it will not work if I include it in the assets/javascripts/mailers.js file... can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, thanks.

```
function myFunction(val) {
if (val.length == 10) {
document.getElementById('search_button').focus();}};
```

Maybe I am calling it incorrectly? Here's the code in the view:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search_mailer, nil, autofocus: true, onkeyup: "myFunction(this.value)" %>
```

is there anything else i have to add into the mailers.js file I included above? Because that is all that is in that file. The only code in mailers.js file is:

```
function myFunction(val) {
if (val.length == 10) {
document.getElementById('search_button').focus();}};
```

Comment: Its probably just a typo, but the path should be: `assets/javascripts/`, not `assets/jacascripts/`

Comment: is the file mailers.js included in the application.js with the require-directive `//= require mailers`?

Comment: Alternatively is the `mailers.js` included via `javascript_include_tag`

Comment: Yes just typo. I have this is the application.js file

    //= require mailers.js

and in the in application.html.erb I have "<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>"

Comment: is there anything else i have to add into the mailers.js file, besides what I included about. Because that is all that is in that file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have probably missed including the file in your manifest file. The manifest file precompiles all the .js files in the `assets/javascripts` directory into one large file. This is the file that is running on your application. If you do not your .js file there, it is not included and that's why nothing happens.

The right way to include your files is:

```
//= require mailers.js
```

in your application.js file. What's more, by default you have

```
//= require_tree .
```

which requires all js files from assets/javascript path.

**if you want to include it specifically for the view, drop tihs in:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "mailers", "data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>
```

For this, if precompilation is false, you have to add the file separately:
   **In config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mailers.js )
```

or 
  **In config/application.rb**

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( mailers.js )
```

The issue might be also that the application precompiles the wrong file if you have a .js and .coffeescript file with the same name. You can try running

```
   rake assets:clean
   rake assets:precompile
```

And run the server again.

Comment: yes, I have //= require mailers.js in application.js
I also have require tree .
when I add <% javascript_include...
I get an error, (I think because this is already in the application.html file)
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: It is not a stylesheet_link_tag, it is javascript_link_tag. Check if you have the application.js included in your <head> </head>  tags.

also, can I have look at the comment?

Comment: yes, sorry that was a typo, I do have <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> in the application.html.erb file

Comment: can you paste me the error you ge when you put

<%= javascript_include_tag "mailers", "data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>
?

Comment: here is the error:
ActionView::Template::Error (Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mailers.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server):

Comment: Go to config/initializers/assets.rb and add the line

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mailers.js )

Comment: Pretty much do as the error tells you to do and you will be good to go :) . I updated the solution. You can also go to config/application.rb and add
config.assets.precompile += %w( mailers.js ) when you go to production

Comment: I added the precompile as described below and the error is gone, but the action is still not firing. I even tried adding something simple like: $(document).ready -> 
  alert('hello') to the mailers.js file and it did not fire

Comment: I figured it out, can you have two script files with the same name? I have mailers.coffeescript and mailers.js? I deleted the coffeescript and now it works.... But I do have a question, can you have both files?

Comment: Try to avoid this, you will have to precompile and clean the assets every time you do this. Besides, why would you need something like that? 

I updated the solution.

Comment: Hristo, okay, would you stick with javascript for now? I am a beginner at rails, and it feels like I would have to learn another language, coffeescript.

Comment: CoffeeScript is just a different version of JavaScript. They do not differ much and both can be used with Rails. CoffeeScript just seems to be shorter to write and thus you can write faster with it. Other than that, there are not many inherent differences. It's pretty much what HAML is to HTML

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Comment: Damn it! I can't believe conflicting .coffeee and .js files with the same names prevented this. thanks mate, I have been dabbling with this for hours.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on `Rails 5`. My `javascript` file was not being loaded when it is the same name of the `coffee` file.

I solved it changing to a different name.

Hope it helps you or someone.

Comment: It did solve my issue using Rails 5.1.4. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including your mailers.js file in the application.js manifest like this?

`//= require mailers`

Comment: yes its included, the error I get in the browser console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout file. If the `javascript_include_tag` is in the head section of the page, try to remove it from there and then put it just before the closing `</body>` tag. Another work around it is to put your code between a document.ready function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  function myFunction(val) {
    if (val.length == 10) {
      document.getElementById('search_button').focus()
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the js file to this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  function myFunction(val) {
    if (val.length == 10) {
      document.getElementById('search_button').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with default Rails 5 app generation. I created a new .js file and on calling a function from the new file it could not find it. I fixed this by adding `//= require_tree .` to the `application.js` file.