# Javascript not running in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails n008 here.

Trying to get JS to work in a rails 4 project. Have Turbolinks running. When page loads, no javascript runs. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <title>Closet</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

welcome.js

```
var ready;
ready = function(){
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
  console.log('page loaded')
  $(".main-button").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax ({
      url: "/users/new",
      method: "GET",
      data: { },
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(responseData){
      $(".newuser").html(responseData);
     }.fail({
       console.log('Something bad happened. Not sure what.')
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` and if you're using `turbolinks 5` you might have to download the `compatibility.coffee` [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee) and putting it under `assets/javascripts/`

include `//= require jquery.turbolinks` in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
...
```

Comment: did you include `//= require jquery.turbolinks` ?

Comment: Yup, did all of that. Unfortunately, nothing. not even my console.log.  In rails, does every .js file I use need a $(document).ready(ready); and
$(document).on('page:load', ready);?

Comment: check your `$.ajax function` like `.done(responseData)` ? it should be `.done(function(data){....})`

Comment: and putting all under `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-button").....
})` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your page load callback is wrapped in your `ready` function and is never called.

See if this works…

```
var main = function(){
  console.log('main() loaded');

  $('#main-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax("/users/new").done(function(responseData) {
      $("#new-user").html(responseData);
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('Something bad happened. Not sure what.')
    });
  });
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log("page loaded")
  main();
});
```

- I've done some tidying up
- You don't really need the "jquery-tubolinks" gem.
- Use an `id="main-button"` instead of a class and on "newuser", now "new-user". ID's are for unique things on a page, like that button and that area you want to target.

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately.  I'm going to keep trying to solve this!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting output? If so, what is it? Where did you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! It took me some time, but

What happened in the end is that I noticed the welcome.js file was not loading in the DOM at all.  After seeing this, I figured it was an assets pipeline issue.

Additionally, I had a 'welcome.js' and a 'welcome.coffee'.  So what I did was I removed the welcome.coffee (as I don't yet know coffeescript and am not using it).  Guessing that maybe it could have some kind of error if welcome.coffee somehow gets compiled into regular JS -> then I would technically have 2 welcome.js's

After that I rand `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:compile` as I read [on this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140048/rails-asset-pipeline-is-not-loading-my-javascript-file-why-wont-this-code-work) about some other issues with assets pipline.

Low and behold, now the welcome.js loads into the DOM, and I can begin to work on it.

Thanks for everyones assistance