# Rails 5.x.x on Heroku (No route matches [GET] /assets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I´m new to Rails. Having an issue after deploying to Heroku. All the assets that are indicated in the controller are not working. Locally all works fine.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/freelancer.min.js"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/portfolio/submarine.png")
```

Assets example from the controller:

```
<img src='assets/portfolio/submarine.png' class='img-responsive' alt='Submarine'>

<!-- Theme JavaScript -->
<script src='assets/freelancer.min.js'></script>
```

Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

**UPDATE:**

Thx for your response @pythia. This worked well with images, but I can't make it work with java scripts and style sheets. It looks like Rails can't find the files, but I've checked JS and CSS and they are present.
The code that I'm using is:

for JS:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'freelancer.min.js'%>
```

for css:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css", rel: "stylesheet"%>
```

Error log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/contact_me.js")
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/freelancer.min.css")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I did everithing described here -> [Rails Asset Pipeline is not loading my javascript file (why won't this code work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140048/rails-asset-pipeline-is-not-loading-my-javascript-file-why-wont-this-code-work)

Basically, every js file should be included in **config/initializers/assets.rb**

Example:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( freelancer.js )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use helpers like `<%= image_tag %>` because the Rails' asset pipeline precompiles your images. It'll "fingerprint" each of your images and add a string of alphanumeric characters to the end of the filename.

So you'll want:

```
<%= image_tag "portfolio/submarine.png", class: "img-responsive", alt: "Submarine"%>
```

If your freelancer.min.js is in the assets/javascripts folder, it gets added to your application.js and should be available from throughout your app.

There's more info in the Rails guide to the asset pipeline:

- [examples of fingerprinted files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)
- ["What is Fingerprinting and Why Should I Care?"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)

Comment: Thx for your response. This worked well with images, but I can't make it work with java scripts and style sheets. It looks like Rails can't find the files, but I've checked JS and CSS and they are present.
The code that I'm using is:
for JS:
<%= javascript_include_tag 'freelancer.min.js'%>
for css:
%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css", rel: "stylesheet"%>
Error log:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/contact_me.js")
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/freelancer.min.css")

Answer (score 0):

You must avoid using HTML tags and use helpers instead :

```
<%= image_tag 'portfolio/submarine.png', class: 'img-responsive', alt: 'submarine' %>
```

and the *script_tag* helper for the script.