# rails - javascript file is not called and only works if it's inside html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I have a view file (index.html.erb) inside of a contact_imports folder in views.

I also have a .js file inside of app>assets>javascripts.. and it's not being called.

When I put the javascript at the bottom of my index.html.erb file it works perfectly.. but I want to have it in the js file. Why isn't it being executed?

Here's the javascript in my view file:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        maxFilesize: 20, 
        maxFiles: 1,
        paramName: 'contact_import[csv]',
        acceptedFiles: ".csv"
     };

</script>

<% end %>
```

Then the one in my .js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        maxFilesize: 20, 
        maxFiles: 1,
        paramName: 'contact_import[csv]',
        acceptedFiles: ".csv"
     };

});
```

I already tried this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32140433/6513002 and it didn't work... any ideas?

Comment: Did you try just `//= require your-filename` in `application.js`?

Comment: What did you name your actual js file?  Because if you are not using rails 5, chances are there was a coffee file created for you when you generated your rails controller(as the coffee gem comes bundled with all non rails 5 apps) and basically if you have a coffee file with the same name as your javascript file in your `app/assets/javascript` path, it will cause conflicts.  If you are in a created rails app, anything in your `app/assets/javascripts` should automatically load. If you are using JS frameworks such as Angular, you will need to do additional requiring in your `application.js` file.

Comment: Also if you are using rails 5 and do not have a coffee file with the same name as your js file, JQUERY no longer comes bundled with rails 5.  You have to add JQUERY gem.  Place the gem in your gemfile(`gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`)and bundle it up.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.3 @kparekh01

Comment: @Pavan I thought since it required tree that I wouldn't need to add every single new js file created?

Comment: @walker did you check that there was no file with the same name but coffee extension?

Comment: @Walker also just check and make sure you have the JQUERY gem in your gemfile.

Comment: @Walker, are you using turbolinks gem inside your gemfile? If yes, you can't use `$(document).ready(function());` because the page doesn't actually load again, so your script under the `$(document).ready` won't get called